# divide 2 row of table and result in percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

```
factors
--------------
totalprice paidprice
400,    300
1000, 1000
500,    500
700,    800
```

My Query

```
select  count(TotalPrice  /paidprice )
from Factors 
where TotalPrice>=PaidPrice
```

I have 4 factore,3customer paid completely their factor but 1 one them did not paid ,it return 3, but I want return 75%

Comment: instead of `count(TotalPrice  /paidprice )` this use `avg(TotalPrice  /paidprice )`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: DONE i add it ..

Comment: Last paid is larger than total price, how can that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I guess you just use a simple calculation can get the percentage.

```
select CONCAT((paidprice * 100 / TotalPrice),'%')
from Factors 
where TotalPrice >= PaidPrice
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11dce9/3)

**EDIT**

I saw you edit your question, you can try to use `SUM` with `CASE WHNE` to calculate percentage.

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN TotalPrice >= PaidPrice THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100/COUNT(*)
from Factors
```

**[Results]**:

```
    | SUM(CASE WHEN TotalPrice >= PaidPrice THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100/COUNT(*) |
    |-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
    |                                                                      75 |
```

Comment: This is not correct, it assumes same price for all products.

Comment: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  avg(CASE WHEN TotalPrice >= PaidPrice THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100
from Factors
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f0f3/10

Answer (score 0):

Find below the query for question

```
select
count( case when nvl(paidprice,0)>0 then paidprice end )/count(*) percentage
from  "table_name"
```

Sorry I forget to multiply by 100

```
select
count( case when nvl(paid,0)>0 then paid end )/count(*)*100 percentage
 from  "table name"
```